# Parsing a string using regex

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm trying to slpit the string `/home/user/test.dat`
I use `String[] split = file.split("(?!.*/)");` but split[1] only returns the first character instead of the whole file name. How would I edit my regex so that it returns everything past the last forward slash?

Comment: Could you post example of result you are expecting?

Comment: I expect `test.dat` while split[0] already returns everything before it

Comment: Do you need to use regex here? There may be better tools go get file name.

Comment: If you can tell me a better solution I wouldn't mind

Comment: Refresh page with this post and see linked duplicate at top.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there's some compelling reason to use a *regular expression*, I would use the simple [`String.lastIndexOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-int-). Something like,

```
String file = "/a/b/c/d/e/test.dat";
int afterSlash = file.lastIndexOf('/');
if (afterSlash > -1) {
    file = file.substring(afterSlash + 1);
}
System.out.println(file);
```

Output of above being (the requested)

```
test.dat
```

Comment: Yes ...if you want only file name than rather go with lastIndexOf() method ...

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**

```
\/((\w+)\.(\w+))$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/OFPjHsx1DlAasSRP)

However, since you are using Java simply load the string into the File helper which can pull out the filename:

**Java**

```
Path p = Paths.get("C:\\Hello\\AnotherFolder\\The File Name.PDF");
String file = p.getFileName().toString();
```